# Terraform - huaweicloudstack provider - unable to login with ssh key

Tags: ssh, terraform

With the help of terraform and huaweicloudstack provider I created ECS instance with specific ssh key, but I cannot login nor with key, neither with admin password. If I create machine manually through webconsole, everything works. Webconsole also shows correct ssh key.

Is there something that needs to be done after machine creation?

```
resource "huaweicloudstack_compute_instance_v2" "testsrv" {
  name              = "basic"
  flavor_name       = "s3.small.1"
  key_pair          = "authorized-key"
  admin_pass        = "somepass"
  security_groups   = ["default", "base"]
  availability_zone = "az1.dc0"
  user_data         = "#cloud-config\nhostname: basic\nfqdn: basic"

  network {
    port = huaweicloudstack_networking_port_v2.port_1.id
  }

  block_device {
    uuid                  = huaweicloudstack_blockstorage_volume_v2.volume_1.id
    source_type           = "volume"
    destination_type      = "volume"
    boot_index            = 0
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
}
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution - use 
`config_drive: true` 
within a instance

Reason:
Without config_drive: true an instance is trying to get config from network. Builtin version of cloudinit in newest centos has bug:

```
failed run of stage init                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------                             
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 652, in status_wrapper                                                                                       
    ret = functor(name, args)                                                            
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudinit/cmd/main.py", line 362, in main_init  
    init.apply_network_config(bring_up=bool(mode != sources.DSMODE_LOCAL))               
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 649, in apply_network_config                                                                                   
    netcfg, src = self._find_networking_config()                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudinit/stages.py", line 636, in _find_networking_config                                                                                
    if self.datasource and hasattr(self.datasource, 'network_config'):      
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudinit/sources/DataSourceOpenStack.py", line 115, in network_config                                                                    
    self.network_json, known_macs=None)     
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cloudinit/sources/helpers/openstack.py", line 645, in convert_net_json                                                                    
    'Unknown network_data link type: %s' % link['type'])                                 
ValueError: Unknown network_data link type: cascading
```

The newest centos has builtin version 18.5, but ubuntu has 20.1 and there is this bug solved, so cloudinit run without errors.

The reason why I was able to start instance manually through console is that huawei's openstack use configdrive module, not network. So the finding with cdrom was actually solution.

So there are two options:

1. Use config_drive: true
   openstack will generate cd drive and mount it into instance. Easy.
2. Update cloud-init in centos
   Start manually instance, get in, update cloud-init, make an image from instance and then use this new image. Harder.